# OnMapLoaded is never call on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to know when the map finished loading to fade in the map, but I can't get the `OnMapLoaded()` callback to be triggered. I'm using `SupportMapFragment` and I see everything OK but still not working. The `OnMapReady` works ok!

**Here is my `onCreate()` code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    View map = findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setAlpha(0);

    createLocationRequest();
    getInstanceGoogleAPIClient();
    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

**Then my `OnMapReady()`:**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
    try {
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.map_style));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }
}
```

**And my `OnMapLoaded()`:**

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    if (mMap != null) {
        View map = findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.animate().setDuration(700).alpha(1).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    }
}
```

**My `Activity` header:**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback):

> This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.

So, check connectivity and make sure that the map is idle.

Answer (score 3):

**Follow below Steps:**

**1)Implements GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.**

Callback interface for when the map is ready to be used.

**2)onMapReady method**

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
```

**3)onMapLoaded() call when maps loads.**

```
public void onMapLoaded() {
       //loaded
    }
```

**Please check point 2 it is important.**

Comment: Sorry, not work for me, even another answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was, as documentation says:

> This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.

I was continuosly changing the location and never completed loading, that was the why onMapReady was never called. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Currently i had a similar problem. I set the map visibility on startup to GONE and show a progressbar. If the map has this visibility it never starts to render and setOnMapLoadedCallback will never be triggered. The solution is to set the visibility to INVISIBLE and the callback works as expected.